# Process.stdout.write appends "true" to the console output

Tags: node.js

Using process `process.stdout.write` to print to the console returns the string with `true` appended to the end

`process.stdout.write` is appending `true` to the value I want to print to the console.

I tried running the same command using `node` in the cli - same result

Command: `node -p "process.stdout.write('hello')"`

`Console: hellotrue`

I expected `hello` to appear.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Bash

Comment: Hint: What is the output of `node -p "1 === 1"`? What does [`-p`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script) do?

Comment: oops (and thank you) @wjandrea - removed the bash tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take another look at your code. some of the common advice for programming forums is to get an example simplified enough that your problem still occurs.

In this case if I write `process.stdout.write('hello')` to a file, and then ask node to run that file, I get the correct response of `hello` back, the word true doesn't show up.

According to the options from node, using `-p` instead of `-e` means you're asking it to print the result of that function call, which was a success.

```
  -e, --eval script          evaluate script
  -p, --print                evaluate script and print result
```

For now try the `-e` flag with your code.